# setOnItemSelectedListener seems to work only the first time the app is launched

Tags: android-fragments, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I'm using a spinner in the menu of a fragment, load its data in the onCreateView. It works fine when the app is launched,however, the spinner disappears when the user navigates to a different fragment and comes back or when the app is opened the next time.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);  
    getSpinnerValues(); //string request to add values to TrailList
}



 @Override                                                               // ...
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);  //temp
    //setData();

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.trailfiller);
    mySpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    ArrayAdapter<Trail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trail>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, TrailList); 
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Trail country = (Trail) parent.getSelectedItem();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+country.getId()+""+country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

[image: when the fragment is first loaded][image: spinner is gone when the user navigates to a different fragment]

The moment it goes blank, the onItemSelected isn't getting triggered either.Strange thing to note is the spinner is consistent when the values are hardcoded. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The onItemSelected would get triggered.Problem was with the ArrayList of size 0. Populating it inside the onCreateOptionsMenu will help. Alternatively,you can add an item to the list inside the onCreateOptionsMenu, which will help you get rid of this issue

```
Spinner spinner= new Spinner();
    spinner.setName("select a country");
    TrailList.add(spinner);
```